# Defining Retrofit2 interface - Method without Response body

Tags: java, rest, retrofit2

I am defining the Call objects in a Retrofit2 interface, to consume an external Rest API.

For most of the calls, we have something similar to :

```
@POST("/api/v1/methodEndPoint")
public Call<MethodResponse> methodName(@Body MethodRequest methodRequest);
```

However, my question is: How should I define a method if there is no Response object (a POST call, with no response body, we just mind about the status). Retrofit throws an exception if I just write the following:

```
@POST("/api/v1/methodEndPoint")
public Call methodName(@Body MethodRequest methodRequest);
```

Thanks for your help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For defining a method without any response in Retrofit 2, the return type of method should be `Void`

You can try like :

```
@POST("/api/v1/methodEndPoint")
Call <Void> methodName(@Body MethodRequest methodRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ResponseBody`. Basically, you can do it like this:

```
@POST("/api/v1/methodEndPoint")
public Call<ResponseBody> methodName(@Body MethodRequest methodRequest);
```

You will have access to `onResponse` and `onFailure` callbacks however there will be no data deserialisation attempt